# Tutorial for sharepoint css branding

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css, design-manager

Hi can you guys point to some awesome css template for sharepoint online.
I already had a look at : [link1](https://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2016/02/sptechcon-2016-css-session-recap/) and [link2](https://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/02/sptechcon-austin-february-2015/#more-2766). Any tutorial also is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The following articles for your reference:

[SharePoint Online - Branding with CSS](http://thebaretta.blogspot.sg/2016/12/sharepoint-online-branding-with-css.html)

[Free SharePoint Online Theme](http://www.topsharepoint.com/avicia-free-sharepoint-online-theme)

[xpecto – Free SharePoint Online Theme](http://www.topsharepoint.com/xpecto-free-sharepoint-online-theme)

Comment: only one of the blog show some css i want to see more css template

Comment: modify the reply as above.

Comment: the second and third link are custom master page that should at all cost not be done,as per microsoft recommendation. This is why am looking for only a css approach.

Comment: @KRobinson can you help here please